# Not being able to use an array with re, search function

Tags: python

I am trying to solver this problem I am having with the code I am writing, I seem to not be able to find any answers about it and doing it the easiest way is the most time consuming. If anyone can help please do all comments are appreciated and I will consider all of them.

```
from re import search
x = "forth" #this value can change so don't think its just a set value 
array = ["first", "second", "third", "forth", "fifth"]

if search(array[0][1][2][3][4], x):
    print(x)
else:
    print("error")
```

This doesn't work, and the only other way I am thinking of doing it one by one doing a huge if statement with an elif part for all the values but before I do that I would rather check if there is an easier way of doing it.

Comment: well, you'll get Index out of range error by the way you're calling the array.

Comment: there's no need to use `re` module, you can just search with `if x in array` => `True`

Comment: I need to use re for later code and these also dont always looks the same as the array

Comment: in theory I could just do a huge or statment

Answer (score 1):

re.search() looks for a specific pattern in a string (not an array of patterns).

Your `array[0][1][2][3][4]` notation does not represent the 5 elements of the array, it corresponds to accessing an element from a 5-dimensional matrix.

To check if any of the words in `array` are present in `x` you can either convert the array to a single pattern or use any():

```
pattern = r"\b(" + "|".join(array) + ")\b" # single pattern, of whole words 
if re.search(pattern,x): 
    print(x)
else:
    print("error")
```

or

```
if any(re.search(p,x) for p in array): # if any(p in x for p in array):
    print(x)
else:
    print("error")
```

Note that the second approach doesn't need the re module and would find substrings in words (e.g. "over" in "stackoverflow") which may or may not be what you want.

Your code currently prints the whole string if it contains any of the words but if your goal is to print the words that are found, you should use re.findall():

```
for word in re.findall(pattern,x):
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found match to be better against lists ... especially large lists.

```
import re

thisCheck = re.compile(r'.+th$', re.IGNORECASE)
array = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]
for x in list(filter(thisCheck.match, array):
    print(x)
```

output:

```
fourth
fifth
```

Comment: Acc to question there will only be one match

Comment: @neilharia7 - in my example I'm just showing that the result returned from how I've structured the search comes back in a list.  My re.compile is looking for any word that ends with 'th' ... that can be easily changed to only get "forth" ... which isn't the number, btw :)